# Facebook's search input is incompatible with Opera 12

Tags: opera, facebook

I try to use the search input in Facebook with my Opera 12.16 but I can't click in, it refuses to get an input focus, it just opens the search options.

I checked the source code and saw that FB uses some custom control instead of regular input controls. Here is what Dragonfly shows:

[image: Facebook with Opera]

[Facebook with Opera](http://s9.postimg.org/parrl2lcf/facebook_problem.jpg)

Is it normal that I can't use FB with my browser? What should I set to make the search input work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, the Facebook search is still working with Opera 12.16. This said, I assume the problem is on your side.

Usually I follow this procedure to find the cause for a problem

1. Temporarily rename Opera's `profile` to `profile.bak` to check if the error is caused by any misconfiguration or extension. If you start Opera without a profile folder, it will automatically create a new, fresh profile.

   Start Opera, go to Facebook and test the search. I assume it's working now. Of course, you do not want to reinstall everything (extensions & settings) so you have to narrow it down. Quit Opera and delete the new profile folder. Rename `profile.bak` back to normal.
2. Set browser identification to *Firefox* under site preferences
3. Disable all extensions one by one
4. Delete all cookies under site preferences
5. Rename `operaprefs.ini`. That's basically a factory reset of all your settings

Comment: Changing the browser identification seems to help a lot.